# what is the meaning of Colette Baron Reid quotes?

Tags: meaning, quotes, proverbs

There is this quote : 
[image: Quote]

Quote :

> There is a surrendering to your story and then a knowing that you
>   don't have to stay in your story.

by : Colette Baron Reid

**Question :**

I am not a native English speaker and i would like to know the meaning of this quote, please ?

Comment: Hello, Carter, and thanks for visiting ELU. Unfortunately, to part-quote @Choster, "Our Q&A format is designed to answer specific, narrowly-focused questions, and is not well-suited to interpreting articles or passages. If you have a question about a particular ... phrase that confuses you, we may be able to assist, but you will need to edit your post to supply ... an explanation of what you do not understand and why.  
I strongly encourage you to take the site tour and review the help center for additional guidance." Here, two metaphors are used in what seem at first glance ...

Comment: to be fairly transparent ways. But detailed analysis of what Reid actually meant by 'surrendering / giving yourself totally to / immersing yourself in your story' and 'later becoming detached from the story, an outside observer' must draw to some extent on opinion and would fit better on the WritersSE site.

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth pointed out, this goes beyond purely "linguistic" meaning. If it comes from a work of fiction, you might also try your luck on Literature SE, but adding some context or a source would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be rephrased as:

> You have options.  One option is to follow, or surrender to, your life
>   circumstances, and the idea that you have built of yourself, which we
>   will call "your story".
>
> Another option is to realise that you are able to change both your
>   circumstances and your idea of yourself, and thus **change** your
>   "story".

Answer (score 1):

When it says 'your story' it really means 'your drama' or 'your head trip' - the story you tell yourself, about your life, or your situation. As Edwin says, it is referring to the ability to 'step outside' your story, and become an observer, which is the first step in being able to change it, or reduce the effect it has on you.